# OnMouseOver doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, wordpress, onmouseover

http://localboyoutfitters.com

Works fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE but only the third hover image works in Safari.

Here is my code for one of the images.. (my tab button is broke so sorry for bad formatting)
(i have a bracket on the a href below but bc of my keyboard limitations I had to take it away)

```
<a href="http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png">
<img src="http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png" alt="LBO_topoffer_SMnew" onmouseover="this.src='http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png'" width="300" height="200" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-205" />
</a>
```

This is placed in a Wordpress widget area.

If anyone has any solutions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try onmouseenter / onmouseleave

Comment: At least here it works fine with Safari. Which Safari version on which  OS?

Answer (score -1):

Better would be to use mouseenter and mouseleave:

```
<a href="http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png">
<img src="http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png" alt="LBO_topoffer_SMnew" onmouseenter="this.src='http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMhover.png'" onmouseleave="this.src='http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png'" width="300" height="200" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-205" />
</a>
```

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are an MS invention and where only supported by IE for a long time. While they are (afaik)  now part of the DOM3 Events specs, the browser support is not the best (Chrome 30+, FF 10+ Opera 11.10+). And Safari even does not support `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` with its current version, so this would obviously not solve the Safari problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily in Jquery, some javascript codes wont work with other browsers you can check jquery,you have to create a function. You have to add this code:

```
<script>
       function mouse(){
            $(document).ready(function (){
                 window.location("anywebsite");
            });
        }
</script>




<img src="http://localboyoutfitters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LBO_topoffer_SMnew.png" alt="LBO_topoffer_SMnew" onmouseenter="mouse();" width="300" height="200" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-205" />
```

Comment: Your answer does not make much sense. In the question images are swapped, but your example looks like you want to change the URL. Further more changing `window.location` does not need to be placed in an a document `ready` callback. Also `mouseenter` is not supported by Safari. If you suggest to use jquery also show how to attach event with jquery using `.on`.